# Prevent connecting separated points when dates are missing

Tags: r, dygraphs

Does someone know how to prevent R dygraph from connecting separated points when the "date" column has missing rows?

I tried setting the `connectSeparatedPoints` argument to `FALSE` but it doesn't work.

```
library(dygraph)
table_test <- data.table(date = as.Date(c("2018-01-01","2018-01-02","2018-01-03","2018-01-10","2018-01-11")),
                     value = c(5,6,4,7,8))


dygraph(table_test) %>% dyOptions(connectSeparatedPoints = F)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Adding at least one of the missing values(NA) will work. And no need to use option *connectSeparatedPoints*. 
Example when the gap is represented by *date*=2018-01-04 and *value*=NA:

```
library(dygraph); library(data.table)
table_test <- data.table(date = 
   as.Date(c("2018-01-01","2018-01-02","2018-01-03","2018-01-04","2018-01-10","2018-01-11")), 
   value = c(5,6,4,NA,7,8))
dygraph(table_test)
```